# Can "to be able to" be used without preposition

Tags: prepositions, modal-verbs, prepositional-phrases, can-vs-be-able

Can the phrase "to be able to" be used without the preposition "to". For example, can you say "I will call you back as soon as I am able?"

Comment: Yes. The stranded _to_ is just an infinitive complementizer, and it's not needed (though it's allowed) once the infinitive has been dropped. So both _I'll call you back as soon as I'm able to_ and _I'll call you back as soon as I'm able_ are OK. As is _I'll call you back as soon as I can_, since _be able to_ is the paraphrase for _can_.

Comment: By the way, auxiliaries with pronoun subjects like _I am, I have,_ and _I will_ are almost always contracted (to _I'm, I've,_ and _I'll_, respectively) in modern English. Uncontracted auxiliaries after pronouns are emphatic.

Comment: Google Books claims 71K instances of [as soon as you are able **to**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22as+soon+as+you+are+able+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but 103K instances of [as soon as you are able](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22as+soon+as+you+are+able%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) without the preposition. Even allowing for the fact that GB guesstimates are often wildly out, that does rather suggest doing away with the preposition is far from uncommon. And it's perfectly valid, as @John says.

Comment: Yes, like many such deletions, it's optional and subject to local and personal conventions. Which can be quite different from one another, since people dream them up themselves, and usually convince themselves that their way is the only possible way to say or understand it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers When I read your comment referring to "GB guesstimates", my first thought was 'why is he mentioning *British* estimates?' I question the use of "GB" as an abbreviation for "Google Books"!

Comment: A common bit of shorthand for "as soon as I can" (or "am able") is ASAP (as soon as possible), which some people pronounce "A-sap," and some "A-S-A-P"):  "Please get back to me ASAP!"

Comment: @TrevorD: I don't really see a problem there - as usual, I only ever refer to **GB** if I've *already* spelled out the full name somewhere earlier in my comment text.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understood it eventually. I was just commenting that I had to read it 2-3 times before realising what you meant by "GB".

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The 'to' is part of an implied infinitive, meaning "I will call you back as soon as I am able to *call you back*". If context is understood (in this case, you have already stated that the intended action is to call back), the preposition is not necessary.

Comment: It isn’t even a preposition.

Comment: Yeah, but you gotta call it something.

Comment: Technically, no. I refer to it as a preposition to be succinct, since 'to' alone is indeed a preposition. As I said earlier in my answer, it is actually the first half of an implied infinitive.